# How to perform a count using LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am using SQL server and in my program I am currently using a count like this:

```
Function NumberOfApplications(inCandidateID As Integer) As Integer

        Dim iCount As Integer = 0

        Dim oApplication As DataModels.Application
        For Each oApplication In Me.Applications
            If oApplication.CandidateID = inCandidateID Then
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
        Next
        Return iCount
    End Function
```

I have created my entities and bought in the correct Imports but I need to know how to perform a count using LINQ and VB. As you can see above I am using the Candidate ID to count. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Something along the line of Me.Applications.Select (s=>s.CandidatId).Distinct.Count()

Answer (score 1):

As @Pleun mentions, you can use the `Count` method, but the method itself has a predicate option, so you can use:

```
return Me.Applications.Count(app => app.CandidateID == inCandidateID);
```

In C#. I always have to think hard what that would look like in VB, this is what my brain tells me. The compiler migt disagree though ;):

```
Return Me.Applications.Count(Function(app) app.CandidateID = inCandidateID)
```

Comment: In Vb only use `1 =` for comparison

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the sql-like syntax, you could also do this:

```
Function NumberOfApplications(inCandidateID As Integer) As Integer   

    Return (From app As DataModels.Application In Me.Applications
            Where app.CandidateID = inCandidateID).Count

End Function
```